# Why does asp.net core support several ways for registering a service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I will create a service `StudentData` from class `Student`:

```
public interface IStudentData
{
    List<Student> GetAll();
}

public class StudentData : IStudentData
{
    public List<Student> GetAll()
    {
        var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { FirstName = "Harry", LastName = "Potter" },
            new Student { FirstName = "Hermione", LastName = "Granger" }
        };

        return students;
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }        
}
```

Here is some ways to register the service:

```
services.AddTransient<IStudentData, StudentData>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData), ServiceLifetime.Transient));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), p => new StudentData(), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

services.AddSingleton<IStudentData, StudentData>();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), p => new StudentData(), ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

services.AddScoped<IStudentData, StudentData>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), p => new StudentData(), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));

services.AddInstance<IStudentData>(new StudentData());
services.AddInstance(typeof(IStudentData), new StudentData());        
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), new StudentData()));
```

So, when to use the first/second/thirth...?

Sub-question: Is there another way to register a service?

Comment: Marked to close as a quick glance at the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) is the answer to this question.

Comment: @Luke Are you sure? With `Transient`, I've given 4 cases to use it, and the document didn't classify. Please reading the question before closing.

Comment: I clicked the link and search for 'Transient' and it came up with a full description of what `AddTransient` is intended for.  Here's a permalink to that bit of the documentation https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#registering-your-own-services

Comment: `AddInstance` isn't a valid option. There's `Singleton`, `Scoped` and `Transient`

Comment: @Luke Did you note the thirth line and the fourth line? I'm not using `AddTransient` at all. That's why I want to classify. Ok?

Comment: @HappyCoding Ok, so you want clarification as to why there are different ways to register the same thing in the same scope?

Comment: @Luke It's just in my question. I said that there are serveral ways to register a service (then showing what they are), ended with the question: when to use the first/second/thirth? I'm not asking about what's the different between `AddTransient`, `Singleton` and `Scoped`

Comment: @HappyCoding I understand now, but it was made confusing because you've included each scope type as individual blocks and then said when to use first/second/third etc.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding you initially, I retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that there are multiple ways of configuring the same thing is simply for convenience and to make it flexible and descriptive to the extent of the C# language.

```
// These are the same, you're just specifying the types and the lifetime:
services.AddTransient<IStudentData, StudentData>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData));
```

In the above declarations, it is descriptive and convenient to simply provide the interface type and the concrete service implementation type - but it is achievable through the C# language in multiple ways.  The first making use of [generic type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx), the second constructor parameters.

The following declarations are also the same, as they are currently written, but are made more flexible because the Add method accepts a `ServiceDescriptor` object, which has [even more overloads for added flexibility](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/Extensions/DependencyInjection/ServiceDescriptor/).

```
// These are doing the same thing, they just configure the resolution of the interface to a bog standard instance of the StudentData class.
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), typeof(StudentData), ServiceLifetime.Transient));
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), p => new StudentData(), ServiceLifetime.Transient));
```

I'll take the last example that you gave (immediately above) and explain a simple use case to show the flexibility of it:

Imagine that the class `StudentData` accepts the current `HttpContext` as a constructor parameter (it is a dependency of the class).  I could configure it so that whenever an instance of type `IStudentData` is resolved to `StudentData`, that it is resolved with the current HttpContext passed into the constructor.

```
// Passing in the current HttpContext into StudentData
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IStudentData), p => new StudentData(HttpContext.Current), ServiceLifetime.Transient));
```

But it's not just limited to passing in specific values, you can provide any method that returns an instance of your class (a factory) - so the possibilities are endless (sort of).

There is no right or wrong one to choose when configuring your dependencies, but I would recommend choosing the one that makes it most clear what is being configured.

Comment: I usually use `ApplicationDbContext` as a parameter in there, but it's in the Controller, not in `Startup.cs`. Thanks!

Comment: btw. there is no `HttpContext.Current` in ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Tseng Thanks, bad example then. I'm not completely clued up on ASP.NET Core :)

Comment: @HappyCoding I hope this answer is of some use to you.  Yes, instead of HttpContext, an instance of your DbContext could work too, or any class or value.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more info about dependency injection here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

For ex: Singleton, means that you will create your service once, and then, use the same instance during all application's life-cicle

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is, if you know the type at compile time, use the generic version `services.AddTransient<IStudentData, StudentData>();`.

When you don't know the type ahead of compile time, i.e. when you iterate through the assembly via reflection and get all types which implement a certain interface, you use the non-generic version, because you can't use generics in this case.

```
foreach(var type in GetAllOfSomeInterface()) {
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ISomeInterface), type);
}
```

Use the `Func<IServiceProvider, T>` ones when you need a factory method to resolve stuff that you can't otherwise via DI, i.e. a setting or option that's determined when the application starts and you can't use `IOptions<T>` (i.e. third party library where you can't change the class to accept the options DI pattern).

Use `services.Add` when you create your own dependency injection system and the overloads for it, or when you need to dynamically determine the scope (Transient, Scoped or Singleton), usually used when you wrap around an existing IoC container. You'll rarely use that though.

Comment: More: asp.net core has new concept `design time` (using `Ctrl + S` instead of `Ctrl + Shift + B` to build project) :)

Comment: @HappyCoding:That's not the point. When you type the interface and class, you know it before the build time. When you iterate through the assembly you don't. You can't use generics with `Type` at runtime, means this is invalid: `services.AddTransient<typeA, typeB>()` or `services.AddTransient<typeof(TypeA), typeof(TyeB)>()`, that's why you need to pass then as parameters.

Comment: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<string>>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<VinaChannelDbContext, string>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

Comment: I've just made some changes based on your answer to modify database. Thanks!